# Are there any working CalDAV clients for node.js that can read/write calendar events?

Tags: node.js, calendar, client, webdav, caldav

I am trying to interface with http://www.sogo.nu/ and cannot find an easy way to list/sync/write calendar events from my application to it using CalDAV.

For reading calendar events there are a few, but writing i couldnt find any that actually worked against SOGo.

The closest i found is https://github.com/gaye/dav but I couldnt even get that one to properly read the calendars yet.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/caldav looks promising (and the server tests work against sogo) but there is no documentation.

Comment: As I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe you might look for a simple solution you can find on my detailled tutorial: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/